# Send an f:param when a ValueChangeListener is invoked

Tags: jsf, parameters, jsf-1.2, valuechangelistener

I want to send a request parameter, everytime a `ValueChangeListener` is invoked. I've implemented it the following way, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Here's the code so you can get the idea.

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{MyBean.code}" 
   valueChangeListener="#{MyBean.codeChanged}" onchange="this.form.submit()">
   <f:selectItems value="#{MyBean.codeItems}" />
   <f:param name="validation" value="true" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: The parameter is the selectItems value?

Comment: No, the parameter is the flag `validation`.

Comment: you can try to add <f:param name="validation" value="true" /> as child of  <f:selectItems >

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<f:param>` is not supported in this construct. For JSF 1.2, it's supported in `<h:commandLink>`, `<h:outputLink>` and `<h:outputFormat>` only. Your best bet is a `<f:attribute>`.

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{MyBean.code}" 
    valueChangeListener="#{MyBean.codeChanged}" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <f:selectItems value="#{MyBean.codeItems}" />
    <f:attribute name="validation" value="true" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

with

```
public void codeChanged(ValueChangeEvent event) {
    UIInput menu = (UIInput) event.getComponent();
    boolean validation = Boolean.valueOf(component.getAttributes().get("validation"));
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you have a resource where I can find out which parameter is allowed where?

Comment: The JSF tag library documentation: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/ Further you may find this article helpful as well to get some new general insights: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/communication-in-jsf.html